# how can I include some custom variable from functions.php?

Tags: php, variables

For example, if I add this code to functions.php:

```
$mysite_address_url="http://my-site.com";
```

And then add this to one of my .php template files(like index.php or header.php):

```
<?php echo($mysite_address_url); ?>
```

It won't work. Why is this happens and how can I achieve this with wordpress please?

Comment: Use constants if a variable won't change: define('SITE', 'xyz'); echo SITE;

Comment: Is it WordPress question? [PHP echo](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress theme files are called thru functions/classes, so variables declared in `functions.php` are not recognized by other theme files, until you specify you want to use the global value of the variable. Do so like this in your theme template files:

```
global $mysite_address_url;
```

you can then use `$mysite_address_url` as you'd like.

To read more about PHP's variable scope, see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Also, if you want to use your website's URL, it'd be better to use the [`home_url()` function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url)

Comment: Don't create globals, stay out of global scope. There are far better solutons than greating globals just to sort a simple issue

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to store it in WordPress options table using function

```
add_option()
```

function as this is site specific data and not post/category specific.

Comment: Don't create globals, there are far better and more reliable methods to solve this issue. Do not create globals in order to solve a simple issue

Comment: Pieter Goosen, can you write a better solution then please?